# Record macro when executing costum add in

Tags: excel, record, vba

I just downloaded a free add in to solve Non Linear Equations with Newton-Raphson's method for Excel it is working great  but when i try to record a macro using this add in I don't find it in the code corresponding to the actions i performed on the add in forms. I already tried many times but  this add in is checked in references but still nothing recording any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use solver and insteed of setting the cell value to 0 just set it to 0.0000001 ;) it should work